# A map for object and string

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a list of some strings like:

```
data/montant
100.00
data/debitAccount
100000000161
data/ftRetour/codeRetour
1
```

I need to make it like this:

```
{data={debitAccount=100000000161, ftRetour={codeRetour=1, messageError=messgaString}, montant=100.00, type=AC01, devise=MAD}}
```

I tried this code where I made the element as a int but it doesn't work:

```
    public void insertElementByPath(Map<String, Object> fluxRetour, String [] elementPath, int element) throws IOException {
         final int targetDepth = elementPath.length - 1;
         
            final String counterName = elementPath[element];
        
            if (element == (targetDepth) && fluxRetour.containsKey(counterName)) {
                // assume objects at the target depth are int
                fluxRetour.put(counterName, (int) fluxRetour.get(counterName) + 1);
            } else if (element == (targetDepth)) {
                // at the target depth, put ints
                fluxRetour.put(counterName, 1);
            } else if (fluxRetour.containsKey(counterName)) {
                // assume object is a map, recur into it for the next counter name
                insertElementByPath((Map<String, Object>) fluxRetour.get(counterName),
                        elementPath, element + 1);
            } else {
                // create a new map and recur into it for the next counter name
                Map<String, Object> emptyMap = new HashMap<>();
                fluxRetour.put(counterName, emptyMap);
                insertElementByPath(emptyMap, elementPath, element+1);
            }
        }
```

It gives the result:

```
{data={type={AC01=1}}
```

Comment: `insertElementByPath(emptyMap, elementPath, element+1);` - do you really intend to append `1` to the string `element` here? Also `counterName = elementPath.toString()` looks odd since `elementPath` already is a `String`. - All that assuming the code you've posted isn't commented out in your actual build. If it is then it's not doing anything at all.

Comment: no it was a mistake i tried with public void insertElementByPath(Map<String, Object> fluxRetour, String [] elementPath, int element)